# Attempting to install java without root, failing

Tags: linux, ssh, java

I have downloaded and ran the self extracting jre bin file. The instillation folder in my subdirectory. Within that same subdirectory I type `java - version` but to no avail, I'm greeted with this message `-bash: java: command not found` which indicates that java has not been installed. What other steps do I need to take to get java working?

I found this on a site, but I'm not sure which file to launch or how to do it:

> The java executable you need to launch is located in a subfolder, called 'bin'. This way of installation will not configure a default 'java' command for you: you must do this manually or always include the full path in your startup script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the path to where you installed it to your standard path. Probably will help a little later to ensure the JAVA_HOME variable is set.

Comment: I'm new to the whole server scene, how do I do this?

Comment: Also bash and similar shells expect binaries run from the current working directory to be run as `./mybinary`.
The `.` tells the shell "current working directory"

Comment: Assuming your home directory is "/home/Deza" and that you installed it in a subfolder named "javabin", you would add something to either /etc/profile or /home/Deza/.profile that looks like this: `export PATH=/home/Deza/javabin:$PATH`

Comment: Thanks, I managed to launch it, but now I'm getting this error: Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.

Comment: Also if the java executable is in that assumed directory: `/home/Deza/javabin/` you can run it like this `/home/Deza/javabin/java -version`

Answer (score 1):

You can't run a binary file that's not in your `$PATH` by using a relative reference to the file. If you're inside of the directory that your java is in, try `./java -version`. the `./` tells the shell to execute the binary that's located in your current working directory and not one in `$PATH`